# Submit R jobs in slurm on a cluster server and saving objects in a different directory than the slurm working directory

Tags: r, cluster-computing, slurm

I am submitting a R job on a cluster server that seems to run correctly as far as I save the results in the same working directory my scripts files are. Actually I want save results from R (via `saveRDS()`) in another directory (e.g. `/var/tmp/results`), but I think that Slurm is redirecting my bash script output to its working directory, causing a `No such file or directory` R error.

I've looked around but I was not able to find a way to specify another path for the job resulting output. Maybe I have used the wrong keys because of my language limitations since I am not a native English, and I before apologize if it is something trivial.

I'll add in the following the script I am calling, i.e. `my_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --array=1-2
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=15000                  
#SBATCH -e hostname_%j.err               
#SBATCH -o hostname_%j.out

module load R

FILES=($HOME/simulation_study_bnp/models/*.R)
FILE=${FILES[$SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID]}

echo ${FILE}

srun Rscript runModel.R ${FILES[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
```

The R script `runModel` sources the code of each file in the `models` folder, load some data and run some analysis. All the necessary files are located in `$HOME/simulation_study_bnp/models/` with `$HOME` being my home directory on the server (e.g. /users/my_dir).

The R script `runModel.R` should save part of the results, but in another path e.g. `/var/tmp/results/` outside my `$HOME`. When I run something like `Rscript runModel.R models/filename.R` everything works fine. After some trials, my opinion is that when submitting 
`my_script.sh` via `sbatch` the process look for the `/var/tmp/results/` under my `$HOME` instead of considering the absolute path, but I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Is `/var/tmp/results` a directory you have created?

Comment: Yes. In addition, running `Rscript runModel.R models/filename.R` directly from bash works fine and populates the `/var/tmp/results` folder as intended.

Comment: If you created `/var/tmp/results` in the login node, then that directory may not exist on the node where your job is running.

Comment: Now I see, thanks. I've also spoken with some person maintaining the server, which explained the same to me, and also that I should move the created files since will be in the node of my job. However, as a quicker solution he just increased my accessible disk quota. 

I may give a try in modifying the script and add the answer here myself just for completeness.

Comment: Just to add, I recommend you taking a look at this workshop materials that I've prepared for R users with Slurm https://uscbiostats.github.io/slurmr-workshop HIH

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out by @carles-fenoy, you have to make sure that whatever directory the jobs are writing to must be accessible by all computing nodes. Usually, large clusters do have a dedicated storage space that is accessible by all nodes (see for example USC's [scratch dir](https://hpcc.usc.edu/support/infrastructure/temporary-disk-space/)). Ask your cluster IT managers to see what's that in your cluster.

Another thing I would mention is that it is worthwhile for you to check symbolic links. You can have a symbolic link in your home directory pointing to another folder located in a node with more space. I do that for my R packages as shown [here](https://hpcc.usc.edu/support/documentation/r/). That way I don't need to worry about running out of space!

Comment: Hi, I'm interested in this topic as well, it just seems that your link to your usage of symbolic links does not work anymore, could you maybe update it? Big Thanks!